Passing authentication from Blazor to API, losing some claims
I have a Blazor Application with Authentication using OpenIdConnect.
Set up as follows:
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    configuration.GetSection("Security").Bind(options);
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    };
});

I also have an WebAPI, with authentication set up as follows:
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // Configure the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = configuration["Security:Authority"];
    });

In my Blazor Server application I call the API and add the access_token in the header.
    var accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

This all works for the authentication part, I can see that user that is authenticated. But I am seeing very different claims in Blazor Server than in the WebAPI. In both places I am getting the user claims from the IHttpContextAccessor.
The Authority is the same in both the API and the application.
Any idea what's going on here?
Thank you!

It's all in the jwt token, just past the token in the jwt.io and check the claims.

openidconnect authentication will get idToken and accessToken. The blazor front-end with openidconnect will extract user claims from idToken itself. While api extra user claims from the accessToken it received.
You could try observe the difference of them by jwt.io.
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
...
    // Save the tokens (including the ID token)
    options.SaveTokens = true;
});

Then
        var authResult = await HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
        IdToken = authResult.Properties?.GetTokenValue("id_token") ?? "ID Token not found";


Thanks! I'll check later, but how do I make sure I get the same claims then?

@Schoof This should be configured in identiy provider (such as Azure AD, auth0, keycloak). You could configure accesstoken to have more claims. For general purpose, accesstoken always have less claims.

I see, thanks! I managed to fix my current issue by passing the id_token instead of the access_token. I'm not sure if that is correct?

@Schoof ah, id_token is not designed to act as bear token. I don't think it will work.

That's strange, because it does work. I pass the id_token to my API and I have everything I need + I'm authenticated. Maybe there's something wrong with the setup of our identity provider?
